# Custom post tag images not displaying

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

Using ACF i've added a custom image field to a particular set of custom post tags. The problem I have is that I cannot get the images to display. Yes, I have added an image to the tag and updated.

```
   $term_id = 26;
    $taxonomy_name = 'tags';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {

        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        $tag_image = get_field('tag_image');
        echo '<a href="?categories=' . $term->slug . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
        echo $tag_image; //this bit doesn't work :(


    }
```

Fixed, the new code is:

```
    <?php

        $term_id = 26;
        $taxonomy_name = 'tags';
        $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

        foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {

            $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
            $tag_image = get_field('tag_image', $term);
            echo '<a href="?categories=' . $term->slug . '" class="one-third column">'. $term->name;

        ?>

            <? if( !empty($tag_image) ): ?>

                <img src="<? echo the_field('tag_image', $term); ?>" />

            <?php endif; 

            echo '</a>';


         }

    ?>
```

Resource for the fix was here http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: What happens on the load? It throws a 404, doesn't make a request, etc.? What is the generated source?

Comment: it displays the list of tags but with no image, no error message

Comment: Does it have `<img...` in the source?

Comment: no, just the the list of tags wrapped in `a` tags

Comment: There's three options for settgin the returned value within ACF for image fields and non of them work, e.g. Image Array,Image URL, Image ID

Comment: I haven't used ACF, `$tag_image` must not have the correct data though.

Comment: I agree, i just can't figure out why and how to fix. Not sure what to test / debug.

Comment: Looks like you need to build the HTML yourself and that that function only builds an array of the image data. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

Comment: yep, tried all that :(

Comment: i think this might be what i'm looking for http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

I'll read through and post results.

Comment: i fixed it using link in previsou comment:) i'll post new code above

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

    $term_id = 26;
    $taxonomy_name = 'tags';
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

    foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {

        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        $tag_image = get_field('tag_image', $term);
        echo '<a href="?categories=' . $term->slug . '" class="one-third column">'. $term->name;

    ?>

        <? if( !empty($tag_image) ): ?>

            <img src="<? echo the_field('tag_image', $term); ?>" />

        <?php endif; 

        echo '</a>';


     }

?>
```

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-a-taxonomy-term/

Comment: You'll need short tags enabled for this solution also don't need to close and open PHP as much as you are.